# Maximizing processing speed of ImageStream using Isolates in flutter

Tags: c++, flutter, image-processing, optimization, ffi

Problem:
As far as my research goes (and someone correct this if I'm wrong) but Isolates in Flutter allow for code to run in parallel, as far as the hardware will permit. In addition, it has no ability to share data objects (it can communicate over ports but strictly won't share data).

The use case this will be applied to is I am working on processing data from the ImageStream with a relatively light function (can run at ~60FPS on average). In addition, the plan is to increase the bitrate of the camera plugin and hit around 60FPS on the ImageStream as well.

The idea is I'd like to create a queue of frames that one thread of execution can push to while another pops.
In essence:

```
ImageStream --Thread 1--> FrameQueue --Thread 2--> ImageProcessing
```

My concern with a single threaded execution is if the image processing takes ~20-25ms to process a frame (on the high end of the predicted speed), by the time the next frame is obtained, the imagestream will have "skipped" a frame that could've been used. For my use case, this is bad.

The idea is that in a dual-threaded execution, the hardware will interrupt thread 2 when a frame comes in, (so if the image processing is slightly slower than the image stream, we'd expect the framequeue to grow over time). This would be the ideal scenario. The issue being that *Isolates can't share data objects*.

Hypothesis:
My proposed solution would be to migrate some of this functionality to a FFI in C++. This begs the question, if I ditch the Isolate pattern and just:

1. Start the image processing thread in C++ (without joining as to hand execution back to Flutter)
2. Then, again using FFI, pipe frames into a shared data structure
   Would this run in parallel with proper shared memory?

In essence:

```
Isolate 0: {
    Manages UI and general Flutter 
Application.
}
Isolate 1: {
    With FFI function: Create shared data structure
    With FFI function: Signals thread for image processing to start
    while(ImageStream.hasFramesToRead()){
        Flutter: Get a frame 
        With FFI function: Send frame to shared data structure
    }
    With FFI function: Signals thread for image processing to end. Get stored results
}
```

My knowledge of the internal workings of Flutter isolates is limited, so I'm not sure if this two isolate solution will work, or if I'd maybe need to separate the image-processing and frame-getting to separate isolates. My concern is also that creating threads in flutter isolates might be unsafe in general.

A simpler solution would be greatly appreciated if anyone has alternate ideas.